# Ubuntu Server 12.04 Will boot with 500GB drive, but not 1TB?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

OK, I am stumped...

I recently set up an Ubuntu Server on an old SS4200-E;  since it is **completely** headless (no way all all to connect a display, no console port, nothing), I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on a different system, then moved the hard drive to the SS4200.

Here's the odd thing--when I installed the server (core + openSSH) on an old Deskstar 500G drive, the system booted fine, came up -- and I am able to SSH to it.

I then installed the server (exact same options) on a Caviar Black 1TB -- and it doesn't boot.  I see disk activity, then nothing.  Does not respond to Pings, can't SSH.

I moved the drive back to my build system -- first it said the ELF header was smaller than expected.  I reinstalled, tried again -- no joy.  Moved it back, it was stuck at the grub boot screen.

I did the fix at [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1598854), and on the build system it boots immediately.  Reinstall in the SS4200;  no joy again.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SS4200 has a PCIe 1x slot. so do yourself a favor and buy a PCIe 1x to 16x flex riser cable from ebay for like $3. use it to install a video card into your SS4200 - just for the installation and trouble-shooting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an Image of your 500gb HDD. Make an Image of your System partition from the 500gb HDD and copy it over the 1TB HDD.

For example *dd* on Linux or *Acronis* on Windows Hostsystem.